# Notification comes in notification list but not pop ups on main screen

Tags: java, android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am sharing two images please have a look on it you will understand my problem

in fist image notification comes successfully as shown better me notification but
I want it to come and show first on main screen as shown in second image just this telegram notification.

```
     public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        //        r.play();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            r.setLooping(false);
        }

        // vibration
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern = {100, 300, 300, 300};
        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);

         int resourceImage = getResources().getIdentifier(remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon(), "drawable", getPackageName());

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.betterme);
        } else {
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.betterme);
        }
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        builder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()));
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setSound(notification);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "Your_channel_id";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            channel.setSound(notification, audioAttributes);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }
        mNotificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
    }
}
```

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rq3u.jpg)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WscX3.jpg)

Comment: have you debugged your code? do you get an error message?

Comment: no error, code run successfully

Comment: did you debug it?

Comment: yes it work perfect

Comment: you understand question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to have a heads up notification.

Note, that the android system decides when to make a notification a heads up notification and has the final say - not you the developer. Here you can find some examples when it does so: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up

Make sure that your setup reflects these. From your sample it seems to be the case, but maybe you have changed the notification channel settings (from the app settings), which override your code preferences (the user has precedence over the app).

Additionally, note that if you swipe the heads up notification in a upward direction (not sideways), Android starts a cool off time, where no heads up notifications from that app appears for a few seconds (or more). You can try that with Telegram or any other app as well. After the cool-off time, it starts showing up again like a heads up notification. This is a way Android utilises to prevent apps to be annoying to users.

Comment: is there any trick to make my notification heads up, can i tell device its important any how

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't do much more. You have to make sure that the Notification channel is created with Importance_high and you can check if the user has changed its importance.

If they did, then you can alert them, but you can't change it programatically. You can remove it and create a completely new channel, but if you do this often, Google might ban/flag you.

Did you check if the settings are changed within Settings > Your App > Notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no problem in the notification. But your channel is already created with normal notification and you update to `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` for NotificationChannel.

`Once the channel is created with priority it cannot be changed`. So you can either change the channel id or uninstall and reinstall and test it.

Comment: please elaborate how can i do this by changing channel id

Comment: Your channel id `String channelId = "Your_channel_id";` to `String channelId = "new_channel_id";` and try it out.